# Implementation of the "Laakso Graph" in Python

Tags: math, graph, networkx

I would like to implement the "Laakso graph", a recursive graph that generates a fractal pattern, utilizing the networkX Python package.

The Laakso graph $L_k$ is defined recursively over the positive integers.

$L_1$ is simply two nodes joined by an edge.

Then $L_i$ is built from $L_{i-1}$ by replacing part of each edge in $L_{i-1}$ with a copy of the standard 4-cycle graph. (Equivalently, replacing each full edge with a copy of $L_2$). Here is a figure of $L_2$ and $L_3$ (albeit with directed edges, which I don't care about).

[image]

I don't have much coding experience (I am a mathematician by training), and honestly, have been using help from ChatGPT to create Python code for implementing different kinds of graphs.

However, this graph is not well-known, and the element of recursion is causing some difficulties in correctly implementing.

Essentially I want to be able to call some function, parameterized by $k$, that creates the $k$-level Laakso graph.

Implementing $L_1$ is trivial, and $L_2$ isn't hard either. But I'm not sure the best way to write the code so that the next level graph always gets the right number of nodes, and the edges in the right places.

**Edit:** In particular, I am confused about relabeling nodes when you are creating the new ones on the next level. For instance, if we are trying to replace the edge (1,2) with a copy of L_2, we need to add 4 new nodes 3,4,5,6 and a few new edges. But then what happens to the original nodes with those labels? Maybe there is a way to index the new nodes by the edge they are replacing, so that we can insert new nodes in such a way where if edge (1,2) is "edge 1" then the new nodes replacing edge 1 are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4. I already feel like this is getting too complicated, but maybe it has to in order to implement this correctly.

**Edit 2:** Another figure for clarity.
[image]

Comment: It looks to me as though edges are replaced by the graph $L_2$ rather than the 4-cycle. Is that accurate?

Comment: @BenGrossmann That is also a valid way to look at it. If you consider an edge as including the two vertices it joins, then yes, we replace each edge with a copy of $L_2$. Geometrically, I think of it as replacing each line with a copy of the 4-cycle (but keeping the two original nodes in place)

Comment: @BenGrossmann On second thought, I think you are right. It seems what I have described is technically the "Newman-Rabinovich diamond graph" https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407520. The "Laakso graph" is really only replacing a *part* of each edge with a copy of C_4.

Comment: I find this really cool, even though as it stands this question could use some code and actual error or hurdle in the implementation.

Comment: Using chatGPT to write code for you is the best way to make sure that you never learn how to write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the following implementation works. I've decided to label the nodes with strings encoding the edge in which the node is being placed. See script and generated image below.

*Note:* With inspiration from Paul's approach, I've refactored the code slightly and made everything more readable. If only the abstract graph is desired, then the references to `pos` and `pos_new` as well as the blocks for finding and setting node positions can simply be removed.

```py
# script to get the Laakso graph L_k
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 3
expansion_motif = [
    (0, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 5)
]
relative_positions = 0.25 * np.array([
    [ 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1],
    [-1, 2],
    [ 1, 2],
    [ 0, 3],
    [ 0, 4]
])

def get_next(G,pos):
    res = nx.Graph()
    pos_new = {}
    for a,b in G.edges:
        # generate node labels
        labels = [a] + [f"[{a}{b}]{i}" for i in range(4)] + [b]
        
        # add edges to graph
        for i,j in expansion_motif:
            res.add_edge(labels[i],labels[j])
        
        # find node positions
        start,end = pos[a],pos[b]
        dx,dy = end - start
        rot = np.array([[dy,-dx],[dx,dy]])
        points = start + relative_positions@rot
        
        # set node positions
        pos_new.update(zip(labels,points))
    return res,pos_new


G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('0','1')
pos = {'0':np.array([0,0]),'1':np.array([0,1])}

for j in range(k-1):
    G,pos = get_next(G,pos)

plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, node_color = 'orange',pos = pos)
```

Resulting drawing:

[image]

Also, here's a figure of L_4.  It was generated by running the above script for k = 4, but replacing the `nx.draw` line with the following block of code:

```py
for k,v in pos.items():
    a,b = v
    pos[k] = np.array([-b,a])
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
nx.draw(G, pos = pos, node_size = 10)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]

Here's a similar figure for L_6, with `node_size = 0` instead.

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks. I ran this successfully and verified the plot for k=1 and 2, though I can't get the display correct for k=3 and greater. I tried some of the different built-in plot layouts from networkX package, including the planar one, but haven't had much success yet. Possibly some nodes have to have a fixed position?

Comment: Actually I don't believe this is correct. Your graph L_3 has 22 nodes, though there should be 6 + (6*4)= 30.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus See my latest edit. The problem is that I was encoding new nodes according to the starting node of the edge. I've now included the entire edge in the encoding.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus I've also modified the script to also draw the graph with the associated recursive embedding

Answer (score 4):

Just a clean-up of @BenGrossmann's brilliant answer to conform with standard networkx graph generator syntax.

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Construct a fractal Laakso graph order k.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

relative_positions = 0.25 * np.array([
    [ 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1],
    [-1, 2],
    [ 1, 2],
    [ 0, 3],
    [ 0, 4]
])
expansion_motif = [
    (0, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 5)
]

def expand(edges):
    for start_point, end_point in edges:
        dx, dy = end_point - start_point
        rotation = np.array([[dy, -dx], [dx, dy]])
        points = start_point + relative_positions @ rotation
        for ii, jj in expansion_motif:
            yield((points[ii], points[jj]))


def laakso_graph(k, create_using=nx.Graph):
    # create Laakso graph
    edges = [(np.array([0, 0]), np.array([0, 1]))]
    for _ in range(1, k):
        edges = list(expand(edges))

    # convert to standard nx.Graph
    positions, inverse = np.unique(np.array(edges).reshape((-1, 2)), return_inverse=True, axis=0)
    g = nx.from_edgelist(inverse.reshape((-1, 2)), create_using)
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, dict(enumerate(positions)), name="pos")
    return g


if __name__ == "__main__":

    g = laakso_graph(4)
    pos = nx.get_node_attributes(g, "pos")

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    nx.draw(g, pos, node_color="gray", edge_color="black", node_size=1, width=0.1, ax=ax)
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It did not at all occur to me that the coordinates of the node in the embedding could be used as a unique node label, but it’s obvious in retrospect. The use of the `expansion_motif` array is also very elegant. Thanks for putting this together!

Comment: Standing on the shoulders of giants, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the abstract graph, and not the coordinates in the plane:

```py
from itertools import chain
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def new_edges(u, v, next_free_id):
    a, b, c, d = range(next_free_id, next_free_id+4)
    return ((u, a), (a, b), (a, c), (b, d), (c, d), (d,v))

def laakso_edges(n):
    edges = [(0,1)]
    next_free_id = 2
    for _ in range(1, n):
        number_of_new_nodes = len(edges) * 4
        edges = list(chain.from_iterable(new_edges(u, v, next_free_id + i*4) for i,(u,v) in enumerate(edges)))
        next_free_id += number_of_new_nodes
    return edges

edges = laakso_edges(5)
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

> In particular, I am confused about relabeling nodes when you are creating the new ones on the next level. For instance, if we are trying to replace the edge (1,2) with a copy of L_2, we need to add 4 new nodes 3,4,5,6 and a few new edges. But then what happens to the original nodes with those labels?

Just make sure you are not reusing labels that already exist. You can do that by maintaining a variable `next_free_id` like I did; or you could use use strings or tuples instead of integers to label the vertices, and label the four "children" of edge `(u, v)` as `(u,v,1), (u,v,2), (u,v,3), (u,v,4)` for instance.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the best way to implement these tuple node labels when the individual coordinates are themselves vectors, instead of just integers?

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus As PaulProdersen pointed out, if you're using coordinates, then you can use the coordinates as labels directly ;-) Or you can use integers or tuples or strings for the node labels, and store the coordinates separately. That is what BenGrossman did.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I am planning on adapting this implementation to different vector spaces and run some metric geometry experiments on them.